Nodejs opus audio streaming transcode on the fly
I'm not used to working with audio/video streams, so I am not sure how many wrong things I'm doing right now.
The intention is to send opus-encoded audio (using 'audio/webm; codecs=opus' from Chrome) through a WebSocket, and on the server side transcode the packets received to PCM to send it to another service.
Then on the client side, I'm doing the next to sending the audio packets
let recorder: MediaRecorder;
socket.on('connect', () => {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      audio: {
        sampleRate: 48000,
        channelCount: 1,
      },
      video: false,
    })
    .then(async (stream) => {
      const options = {
        audioBitsPerSecond: 256000,
        mimeType: 'audio/webm; codecs=opus',
      };
      recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
      recorder.ondataavailable = async (e) => {
        if (e.data.size <= 0) {
          return false;
        }
        const buffArray = await e.data.arrayBuffer();
        socket.emit('audioStream', new Uint8Array(buffArray));
      };
      recorder.start(20); // to get chunks of 20ms
    })
})

On the server side, I have tried with audify, node-opus and prism-media to transcode the packets, but I'm getting some error with any of them. And basically, my code in the server is
With Audify
ws.on('audioStream', message => {
  const buffer = Buffer.isBuffer(message) ? message : Buffer.from(message);
  const decoder = new OpusDecoder(48000, 1);
  const frameSize = 960; // 20ms
  const decoded = decoder.decode(buffer, frameSize);
  // the rest of the code to use the PCM obtained
})

The error here is "TypeError: The compressed data passed is corrupted", and similar error obtained from node-opus
With Prism Media
ws.on('audioStream', message => {
  const buffer = Buffer.isBuffer(message) ? message : Buffer.from(message);
  const demuxer = new prism.opus.WebmDemuxer();
  const decodingStream = new prism.opus.Decoder({
      rate: 48000,
      channels: 1,
      frameSize: 960,
  });
  const decoded = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      demuxer.pipe(decodingStream).on('data', (chunk) => resolve(chunk));
      demuxer.write(buffer);
    });
})

Getting the error message Did not find the EBML tag at the start of the stream
Then, what could be a good implementation to make the transcoding even if is not Nodejs the solution?
